# Variation in data usage

Tags: browser, pdf

Does changing the settings of Web browser (Firefox and Chrome) to *preview* a pdf over *download (save) it* change the data usage?

Comment: Does previwing a local pdf file in your browser use bandwidth, that would entirely depend on the content of the pdf itself, if all the content is contained within the local file it would use no bandwidth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what is meant by "preview".

Typically, opening a PDF inside the browser still downloads the data for the file, it just opens the file inside the browser and the data is saved inside the Temporary Internet File cache rather than in your Download directory.

If you are using a website that has its own PDF rendering capability built-in, this may use less data, but this will depend on the site and its capabilities and methods.

Comment: Ok, so previewing the file with the browser's PDF-reader would consume the same amount of data as when downloaded? It shouldn't matter when the previewed file is saved in PC's folder?

Comment: You need to stop using the word "preview" in this context because that is not what you're doing. And that is correct.